# .click is not triggered once change from .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I have below code

```
$(document).on('click','#container.pagination .active', function(){

                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);
                });
```

returned error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'

And I found once I disable JQuery UI 1.9.0 which use JQuery 1.8.2, problem will be resolved. But the JQ UI is vital part of my project so its not able to be removed from the page.

I tried an alternative that can help me achieve the same result without using .on, but seem its not even triggered. Is there any syntaxual mistake?
I replaced

```
$(document).on('click','#container.pagination .active', function(){
```

with

```
$('#container .pagination .active').click(function(){
```

So now its like this:

```
$('#container .pagination .active').click(function(){
                    alert(loadData(page));
                //$(document).on('click','#resultBox .pagination .active', function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                    //echo $page;
                });
```

However, the function is not even triggered...

**Is there a difference when I use the .on VS .click in this senario and that is the cause of its mal-function?**

**=========A bit update on troubleshooting===================**
Here is the further info I found in the error report by Chrome Browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' jq_iface_testScores_with_pagination.js:176
(anonymous function) jq_iface_testScores_with_pagination.js:176
c.extend.ready jquery.tools.min.js:38
L jquery.tools.min.js:45
```

Does it means it also deals with jquery tools as well....This is getting wild...
Please help.

**====Most current findings--ACTUAL ISSUE FOUND! how to resolve it?============**
As previous error found, the actual problem lays with JQ Tools 1.2 which utlizie JQ1.7.2. I think somehow it contradict with my JQ1.9.1's .on function. I tried in multiple pages. Its tested that even simply load the JQTool 1.2 will cause problem without even actually using it.
*How can I resolve this issue without remove jquerytool 1.2? The same error msg was returned every time.*

**==RESOLUTION======**
After **smerny**'s persistent help, I came to a resolution, that finally, **the problem is actually deal with OUTDATED jquery.tool library**. **The problem is cause beacause the jq.tool lib was 1.2.3 instead of 1.2.7.** Sometimes, the things are just so simply but take long time to understand and explore.

Aagain, thanks **smerny**! Here is your rep you deserved :)

Thank You!

Comment: If element with class .active is added dynamically, then event bound with on will work and event bound with click won't

Comment: `click(...)` is a shortcut for `on("click", ...)`, but when you add the context in the `on()` it makes a difference... try just replacing `$(document)` with `$("body")`

Comment: Thanks Karaxuna! So, is there an alternative, without using .on while achieve the same effect? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you want to use it? it has alternative `live` in older versions of jquery

Comment: I want to use jq1.9.0 and .live is deprecated at that point. so .on is the only alternative, yet, because its somehow, not working well with jquery ui 1.9.0, so I may need to change soemthing else other than .on. Or, you have a better suggestion? thaks!

Comment: @Adam Any reason why you aren't upgrading jQuery UI as well?

Comment: @Ian, currently I am testing this page in jq1.8.2, so ui 1.9.0 is eaxact match, its troublesome for me to understanding how could ui be conflict with jq itself....

Comment: In your selector you don't have a space between `#container` and `.pagination` - is that on purpose? Because that has a lot of meaning in CSS. Have you tried `$('#container .pagination .active').on('click', function(){ }`?

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a test page of this happening?

Comment: @Charlino, currently the code is like '$(document).on('click','#container .pagination .active', function(){', so there is definately distance between the css element. thanks though!

Comment: @Chad, never use jsFiddle, may take a bit to learn, but I will see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between

```
$(document).on('click','#container .pagination .active', function(){
```

and

```
$('#container .pagination .active').click(function(){
```

Is that in the first one, it uses delegation. This means that the elements in the selector do not have to be there before the bind is made.

In the second one, the elements will need to be there before the bind is made.

If `$(document)` isn't working, try selecting the body instead:

```
$("body").on('click','#container .pagination .active', function(){
```

This is only necessary if you are dynamically loading these elements at some point... if they are loaded right away, then I'd assume you just need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready( function() { ... })` block:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("body").on('click','#container .pagination .active', function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the possible options:

```
 $(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+
    $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.4.3+
    $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler); // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: He's already using 1.7+, and upgrading to 1.7+ and he's already using `on()`